# Issue installing rJava on aix7.1.3

Tags: r

I have installed the 32bit version of R 3.1.1 on AIX 7.1.3

I am in the step of installing the rJava package from the R shell using the command: install.packages("rJava")
However, I am getting this error:

**Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/src/contrib
Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") : unable to resolve 'cran.r-project.org'
2: package 'rJava' is not available (for R version 3.1.1)**

It seems that R is unable to connect to the internet to download the package. 
I have tried several mirror sites.

Any idea how to resolve this issue in AIX?
 Is there also an alternative option to install rJava manually not through the install.packages() R command?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to compile the package with devtools:

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('s-u/rJava')
```

Make sure to have the correct javac in your path.